# Is their any time advantage of using @property decorator on django models instead of saving the field directly into database

Tags: python, django, database

So a field that can be computed like full_name from first and last name, we should use the @property to compute the full_name. But when we required to get a list of all 'n' persons with their full name. the full_name will be computed 'n' times which should require more time than just getting the field from database(if it stored as separate field already!).

So is their any processing time / db fetching time advantage /disadvantage of using @property to compute full_name?

(Note: I have considered other advantages of @property like reduction of database size, not worrying about change in first or last name without change in full name, setter function to set first and last name etc. I just want to know the processing/ db fetching time advantage/disadvantage  over saving full_name into database.

Comment: processing time / db fetching will depend on your use case. Try it and see what performance difference it makes. In practice, I don't think the difference will be measurable for  your `full_name` example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technique that you're talking about is called [Denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). This is quite *advanced* technique.

> Denormalization is a strategy used on a *previously-normalized* database
>   to increase performance. In computing, denormalization is the process
>   of trying to improve the read performance of a database, at the
>   expense of losing some write performance, by adding redundant copies of data or by grouping data.

It's opposite to database [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). And you always should start your application with normalized database.

If you don't have any serious problems with performance, I'd advise to not do this. If you have problems, try other solutions first to improve your app speed.

> **First Normal Form(1NF):**
>
> - *It should only have single(atomic) valued attributes/columns.*

Very basic example of disadvantage: `UPDATE` statement. You'll need to access 2 columns in table + calculation for full_name.

Anyway, your full_name example is so simple, that you should definitely do this with @property

---

More on this topic:
[Difference Between Normalization and Denormalization](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-normalization-and-denormalization.html)

Comment: I think Its a good explanation.
In the real case, I have a sale invoice table and sale invoice items table with a Foreign key relationship. Now each item has sell value and total invoice value is the sum of all sale value. So should I use @property to calculate the sum (require DB Query) or Just store the sum as well, in consideration of performance efficiency?

Comment: @ashwinbande I'd use property. But read also about cached_cached property, maybe it will fit your needs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional